# Mac Office 2008 database error during startup

Tags: mac, microsoft-office

After installing, and then uninstalling (it was a trial and I decided not to purchase) a copy of MS Office 2011 for Mac, my installation of MS Office 2008 for Mac is showing the attached problem messagebox during splash screen.

[image]

After clicking through this, Word, Excel and Powerpoint seem to function normally except for lack of certain fonts that used to be there before e.g. Tahoma.

Things that did not help so far:

- Rebuilding the database as suggested by the error message - the Database Utility says the database cannot be repaired
- Reinstalling Office 2008 for Mac from install media

Any ideas? The lack of fonts is actually more annoying than the error message, but I suspect one is connected to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across the same issue after copying my old documents over to my new laptop.
Turns out the engineers at Microsoft thought it would be a good idea to store settings and stuff within my documents folder.

Try deleting the folder "Microsoft User Data" within your "Documents", alternatively repair permissions on it.